# How many S3 put requests for a code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

How often does the code pipeline put to S3? I have used up 1936 requests out of the 2000 available for free each month with 12000 forecasted requests. Do we send a bunch put requests only when the pipeline is being created or does it make more requests every time we use the pipeline? In that case is there a way to stop making these put requests? (Are they mandatory for the pipeline to work?)

New to AWS so any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks : )

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome-introducing-artifacts.html *"Stages use input and output artifacts that are stored in the Amazon S3 artifact bucket you chose when you created the pipeline. CodePipeline zips and transfers the files for input or output artifacts as appropriate for the action type in the stage."*

Comment: So the number of artifacts created depends on the number of files in the code we are trying to send? @luk2302 Is it common to have as many as 1936 put requests? Also is there any work around to not use put requests since I only have 2000 of them per month..